# Python: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object , How to resolve it?

Tags: python

A digital root is the recursive sum of all the digits in a number. Given n, take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has two digits, continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is produced. When I call it like this:

```
def digital_root(n):
    if(0<n<10):
        return n
    else:
        list = [int(x) for x in str(n)]
        return digital_root(sum(list))

digital_root(942)
```

I get:

> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str
>   of an object

Comment: what value do you feed to this?

Comment: You do know that a much easier way to get the same result is `n % 9`?

Comment: You can increase the recursion limit using [sys.setrecursionlimit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit), but you might want to reevaluate your algorithm if you are using very large numbers.

Comment: digital_root(942)

Comment: @RoryDaulton I think you mean `n % 9 or 9`, because `9 % 9` is `0`, rather than `9`.

Comment: Note that when you ask a Python question you should include the *entire* traceback, not just the summary.

Comment: Can not reproduce the error. Do you really get the error on `942` or when passing something else to the function?

Comment: I ran this code and it worked for me. Are you using an IDE or ipython or something? As a minimum, rename `list` to something else so you are  not masking the `list` object.

Comment: Thanks for reminding@RoryDaulton

Comment: @WayneWerner: I meant `(n-1) % 9 + 1`--I forgot that `9` is wanted rather than `0`. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @RoryDaulton thanks a lot , I just tweaked out few lines if(n%9==0 and n!=0)return 9 else return float(n)%9

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty trivial to convert this to the iterative (or is that [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)?) version:

```
def digital_root(n):
    str_n = str(n)
    while len(str_n) > 1:
        n = sum(int(x) for x in str_n)
        str_n = str(n)
    return n
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem. That being said, procure to use iteration when possible, is more efficient, as show by **Wayne Werner**.

Now, if you do a little [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) search you can find that you don't even need to iterate over anything

```
def digital_root(n):
    if n<0:
        n = abs(n)
    if n%9==0 and n!=0:
        return 9
    return n%9
```

Comment: if(n%9==0 and n!=0):return 9 else return float(n)%9

Comment: @DarshShukla the float conversion is unnecessary